# How to get the blob size of Cloud Storage object?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I could get the size from `gsutil`.

```sh
✗ gsutil du gs://<bucket>/test/1561402306
100          gs://<bucket>/test/1561402306
```

I could confirm the length and content via `download_as_string`. However, the `size` property always returns `None` from SDK/API.

How could I get the size of Cloud Storage object without downloaded?

```py
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
print(len(blob.download_as_string().decode()))
print(blob.size)
```

Output:

```
100
None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `get_blob()` to get the blob `blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)`
instead of `bucket.blob()`, which is a factory constructor for blob object.

Look to the difference between the two functions at [get_blob()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.get_blob) and [blob()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.blob).

Answer (score 14):

to obtain the object's metadata you should use the method "get_blob" when retrieving the blob.

I have edited your code like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name) #here you use the method get_blob
print(len(blob.download_as_string().decode()))
print(blob.size)
```

You'll be able to access the size of the object now and you will also have access to the other metadata, for more information about it check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-python).